# prove that $\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt{2}}}}}_{\text{n radicals}}=2\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}$

Tags: induction, problem-solving

Provide a complete proof for the statement: prove that $\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt{2}}}}}_{\text{n radicals}}=2\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}$

Comment: I haven't attempted the problem myself yet, but think "half-angle formula."

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viète%27s_formula